# Multiple associations between 2 models - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to code the following situation for a Rails 5 application.
I have these 2 models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mastered_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'game_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :played_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'game_id'
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dungeon_master, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

The general idea of this is that any User can have many played and mastered Games, and any given Game belongs to just one User (a DungeonMaster) and has many Users playing on it (the Players). I know that it would probably be easier to just use the models names, but this is much more lexical, besides, the associations would probably collision with each other.

My migrations for now look like this:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.integer :game_id
      t.string :secret_key
      t.belongs_to :dungeon_master, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :picture
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateGamesUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :games, :users do |t|
      t.index :game_id
      t.index :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to work for me. For example, when I try to add a a dungeon_master to a Game in rails console, like so:

```
u = User.new(name: 'Jon')
g = Game.new()
g.dungeon_master = u
```

This returns the error `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute user_id`.
Moreover, I'm having trouble with the bidirectionality of the many to many association, when I add a User to a Game like:

```
g.players << u
```

The user is added but when I try to access that User played_games, it return no game. I'm probably missing something but I cannot figure what.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some of your directionality flipped. Whichever model has the `belongs_to` will receive the foreign key in the database table. Right now you have a `games` table with a `game_id` column. What you want is a `games` table with a `user_id` or `dungeon_master_id` column (honestly, it's much easier just to use the default foreign key names instead of specifying manually in the models):

```
create_table :games do |t|
  t.references :dungeon_master 
  # other columns
end

create_table :users do |t|
  # other columns
end

create_join_table(:games, :users)
```

Then your models are a little simpler:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mastered_games, class_name: 'Game', inverse_of: :dungeon_master
  has_and_belongs_to_many :played_games, class_name: 'Game'
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dungeon_master, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :mastered_games
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, class_name: 'User'
end
```

And you shouldn't have any trouble with the following:

```
user = User.new(name: 'Jon')
game = Game.new(dungeon_master: user)
```

Comment: Dude, that was fast. Thanks for the asnwer, it didn't solve my problem right away but it did most of the work. I've added foreign keys to the has_many (for the User model) and the belongs_to (for the Game model) and it's working like a charm, at least once I persist the models, not just playing around the console.
Again, much appreciated!